# Rendering HTML code from EmacsLisp representation

Tags: html, emacs, rendering

I can parse the html using the `libxml-parse-html-region` function.

But I don't know how to render it back into HTML.
The `shr.el` functions doesn't seem to do anything at all.

What I tried is this.
I wrote an HTML string

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

and parsed it with `libxml-parse-html-region` function and pretty printed with `dom-pp` function. Like so

```lisp
(dom-pp (libxml-parse-html-region (region-beginning) (region-end))))
```

This results in the following lisp representation

```lisp
(html nil
 (head nil)
 (body nil))
```

being inserted into the buffer. Which is OK.
The next step does not work.
I want to render this lips representation
back into the HTML representation.
I tried to use the `(shr-render-region)` with `(region-begining)` and `(region-end)` function calls as arguments, like so

```
(shr-render-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
```

I mark a region and call the above code interactively.
However, this does not do anything as far as I can tell. There is nothing inserted into the buffer and the `shr-render-region` does not return a string.

So how do I render the lisp representation back into HTML code?

Update 1:
The `shr-render-region` renders HTML code into formated text, so it's not going to work.

Update 2:
The `shr.el` functions won't work, it looks like they are for rendering HTML in an emacs buffer, but not rendering the code (the html string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dom-print` function can be used to print the lisp representation back into HTML text.

Comment: Or `shr-dom-to-xml` to return a string.